# Вопрос изменен, но изменение не видно в revisions

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

В [ленте вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions) у моего вопроса указано: [изменен ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478201/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b/?lastactivity) и автор изменения [Floyd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/197927/floyd).
Но никаких изменений не видно на странице [revisions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/478201/revisions).
Похоже это баг. Или это не баг?

Лента вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница Revisions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

В ленте "текущих" вопросов слово "изменён" означает любую активность касательно этого вопроса. Это может быть: правка, начало конкурса, переоткрытие, новый ответ, правка к ответу.

В данном случае похоже что Floyd поместил там ответ, но потом удалил его. Это происходит довольно часто, см. [Last activity on question shows modified by user who did not ask or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75828)

Comment: Дополню, что вопросы также бывают "изменены" Духом Сообщества. В этом случае в вопросе нет вообще никакой активности, он просто поднят в ленте вопросов для привлечения внимания.

Comment: [Здесь](https://i.gyazo.com/aed19b59b8b1dc3bcddae03eaa4b3f5a.png) тоже ув-мый Nicolas Chabanovsky, видимо, [удалил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-smtp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC) свой ответ? Последние правки датируются 2015 годом. Спасибо.